# Registering an Aggregate UDF in Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I am trying to follow the steps [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/table/udfs.html) to create a basic Flink Aggregate UDF. I've added the dependencies () and implemented

```
public class MyAggregate extends AggregateFunction<Long, TestAgg> {..}
```

I've  implemented the mandatory methods as well as a few other: `accumulate, merge, etc`. All this builds without errors. Now according to the docs, I should be able to register this as

```
    StreamExecutionEnvironment sEnv = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    StreamTableEnvironment sTableEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.getTableEnvironment(sEnv);
    sTableEnv.registerFunction("MyMin", new MyAggregate());
```

But, the `registerFucntion` seems to want a `ScalarFunction` only as input. I am getting an incompatible type error: `The method registerFunction(String, ScalarFunction) in the type TableEnvironment is not applicable for the arguments (String, MyAggregate)`

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import the `StreamTableEnvironment` for your chosen language which is in your case `org.apache.flink.table.api.java.StreamTableEnvironment`.

`org.apache.flink.table.api.StreamTableEnvironment` is a common abstract class for the Java and Scala variants of `StreamTableEnvironment`. We've noticed that this part of the API is confusing for users and we will improve it in the future.